# get file from my page in java

Tags: java, blob

I have an input type file in my page and I would like to get the file again from my server in Java:

html:

```
<input id="myFile" name="myFile" type="file">
```

I upload a file, and I check it with:

```
var urlToJava =  URL.createObjectURL($('#myFile')[0].files[0])
"blob:http://localhost:8080/71dd8260-33f7-41a9-b30e-f9080f75b970"
```

I send this to my Java server and received,

```
private boolean uploadFile(final String fileUploadUri ) throws Exception {


  // fileUploadUri = "blob:http://localhost:8080/71dd8260-33f7-41a9-b30e-f9080f75b970"
   //how to get the extension?
   File file = File.createTempFile("fileRecovered", ".txt", new File("."));

   //Blob blob = how to get the blob from fileUploadUri? 
   InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
   byte[] buff = new byte[4096]; 
   int len = 0;
 }
```

How can I get the data I don't know?

Comment: What is the result of the code posted when run?  This is essential information in a question here on SO....  "Is that code correct" does not yield very good responses here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws FileUploadException, IOException {

    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    FileItemIterator items = upload.getItemIterator(request);
    while (items.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream fis = items.next();
        if (!fis.isFormField()) {
            InputStream input = fis.openStream();
```